# Javascript random quote generator NO REPEAT

Tags: javascript, random, generator, quotes, repeat

Please refer to www.thisyeariwantto.com This is the js code I am using to display "random" quotes... but the problem I keep having is that the quotes on the array repeat themselves. I want the user to come in click and click without ever seeing the same quote twice. How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.

```
function jargonator(){
$('#head').text("This year I want to...");
$('#tag').text("");

var fragments = shuffle(
["gym","Fall in love(cliche), be happy and work abroad","stop fighting with my boyfriend","to finish things, no matter how long they take or how silly they are", "I'LL FINISH EVERY THING I START !","adopt a Koala","write a book","make a million","grow a pair","get married","drink less live more","figure out where i buried her","Give my girlfriend a real orgasm","Read more books","Save more money","Lose weight","Redecorate","Take better photos so that I can gain more instagram followers","Stop it with the #selfies","Travel","Stop cheating on my husband","Sell old unwanted stuff on eBay","Do something for charity","Get new boobs","Spend more time with kids","Spend Less time on Facebook","Totally revamp my wardrobe","Try a new hairstyle... down there ;)","Have a threesome","Get a six-pack... of premium artisanal beer","Eat less chocolate","Socialise more in real life rather than Facebook","Drink less alcohol","Eat an entire bowl of Ben & Jerrys without feeling guilty", "Start my own business","Recommend this site to all my friends","Tell Susan I have feelings for her","Stop hitting my girlfriend","Do less cocaine","Quit smoking","Get a promotion","stop saying, 'Ooh, that feels nice' whenever the security guys frisk me at airports.","work with neglected children. (my own)","balance my checkbook. (on my nose).","Learn how to use Twitter","Stop sleeping with my brother’s fiancée","Have a better relationship with my parents","do less laundry and use more deodorant","assure my lawyer that I will never again show up drunk at a custody hearing.","start shaving my legs again","Run a half or full marathon","Call people more than text","Stop texting 'LOL'","Stop sexting my cousin", "Watch less reality TV","Stop treating my cat like a real person","Stop buying every iphone that comes out","Stop sleeping with my ex","Stop faking my orgasms","go to the beach more often","get penis reduction surgery so my girl lets me fuck her in the ass","start pretending i'm gay so I can get free drinks at the rainbow room","stop lying on my resume","Exclude McDonald's from my daily diet","Stop considering ketchup a vegetable","stop pretending I have friends","Make at least one REAL friend","Learn how to spell 'thru'... 'thrugh'... 'trhouh'.... fuck it.","Get into a fight so I can finally use my mma skills","stop watching mma so my girlfriend stops thinking I'm gay","Paint my balls blue so I always have an excuse for my gf to jerk me off","Tell Rebecca to fuck off, she is such a bitch","tell my son he is adopted, and his real name is not Kyle... it is Rodrigo.","Stop being a hipster because everyone is doing it","Stop being a hipster, thats so 2013","stop taking naked pictures in snapchat","Reduce, reuse, recycle :)","Graduate!","Be happy!","Take more pictures","Learn how to twerk","stick my tongue out and not feel dirty...like Miley","ride naked on a wrecking ball...with a hammer","make my first legal pornographic movie...with a hidden camera...","learn japanese curse words","star on a rap video as one of the hoes in the back","get my freak on...it's been off way too long...and people are talking","stop showing my boobs so I get more likes","make my momma proud","stop sleeping with my boss's daughter","wear condoms more often","tell him he is not the real dad...","Have intense lesbian sex in public places.","stop making new year's resolutions.","finally dunk.","stop doing Molly","Eat the still beating Heart of Jeff Gordan","get rich doing what i like","Do the splits!","speak up","finally open my own practice","meet a girl","be more positive","Stop being an intern and get a job.","travel to where the soul meets body.","get a tattoo","be fearless","stop curating, start creating", "continue to make my boyfriend happy to the best of my ability.","leave The City and start really living","become a mermaid","Quit 'Call me maybe'","Do my Irish penpal", "Have more bacon, have more sex","study quantum physics so I can RULE THE WORLD","stop biting my nails","drink quality instead of quantity","sleep completely naked in a middle of a peaceful forest","Take a shower with Ryan Gosling","break the circle of no-life", "BOOMSHAKALAKA!!!","Break the Internet", "go back to the future","play hide & seek with strangers on the internet","file a complaint to the Karma Police","NOT fall in love","Stop making a Morgan Freeman voice when talking about Nelson Mandela's death","Make my husband allergic to viagra... i am tired!! :)","cast a worldwide campaign to protest against animal abuse","drink over 20 Mezcal shots in a row","star in the next Star Wars movie","get inspired","stop thinking 'It'll be our year... I'm the only one being the Zombie","Try and see if I can live on wine and sushi... and nothing else","Prove Einstein was wrong","Buy a hammock and work from there","forget about Teen Spirit","find the second star to the right, and go straight on till morning","Leave Narcissus alone","write a novel","make the team","go to all my AA meetings","spit in the face of convention","Somewhere I've never been yet","learn a new recipe", "Paint!", "learn to meditate and at least take one weekend for myself to travel.",]
)

$('#c').click(function () {
    change(1000);    
});

function change(time){
    $('#tag').animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, time, function () {
        $('#tag').html(fragments.pop()).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, time)
    });
}

function shuffle(o) { //v1.0
    for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};
change(0);

}
```

I really need help. If you need to see any other code of any of the other files please let me know. thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have an umlimited amount of quotes, if so that would be something worth seeing.

Comment: Shuffle your `fragments` array (like a deck of cards) and then iterate through it one by one from index 0 to the end.  E.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can just poping it from array

```
for( var i=0;i<fragments.length;i++){
   str += fragments[i].pop();
   if(i <fragments.length-1){str+=stub;}
}
```

if you do so, then it remove quote and you never have dublicates.

and before doing this, you can sort array random, then you will have different quotes every time

something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/donce17/CeLqL/).

Comment: Ok. what do you mean by sort array random before? what would that code look like?

Comment: this is working for me great, only the quotes change every few seconds, i need them to change only when user clicks on button.

Comment: it's depending on you how you want. you can do as you want.  [demo with button click](http://jsfiddle.net/donce17/CeLqL/2/)

Comment: ok. got it.
but i find that some quotes still repeat. I am working with around 90 different quotes. how could i make sure once the user comes in, never sees the same quote twice untill all 90 quotes have been read?

Comment: uploaded your code to the site. thisyeariwantto.com so you can see it live. some quotes do repeat.

Comment: if you reload page, then of course you will get same quotes.. then you need store in to local storage or do something different. but if you click button, you never get same quote.

Comment: you get the same quote after 60 or so clicks.

Comment: it's not possible. check your quotes array. its possible just when you change all quotes, then you will see same all the time

Comment: Ok. so I thought we had solved this... but it seems the more quotes I add to the array the more they repeat. How is this possible? Here is the code for the entire JS. Maybe something is interfering with the code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/donce17/uFh6w/1/ here is test case where you can see, that code working how it should! one quote per array!

Answer (score 0):

We cannot control the value returned by Math.random() as you expecting. However try this workaround, every time a value is generated add it to another array, say mylist

```
var fragments =[
["quote1", "quote2", "quote3","etc", ... ]

var selected;
var temp;

var str = "";
var stub = "";
for( var i=0;i<fragments.length;i++){
temp = fragments[i][Math.floor(Math.random()*fragments[i].length)];
while(selected.contains(temp)){
temp = fragments[i][Math.floor(Math.random()*fragments[i].length)];
}

selected.push(temp);
str += temp;
if(i <fragments.length-1){str+=stub;}
}




$('#tag').animate({opacity:0.9},1000).append(str);

}
```

Eventually at some time all randoms get generated after that clear mylist and continue. At least random wont repeat until all elements in your fragments get selected once.